# Wordpress and metro gallery not visible

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Is anyone who will be able why this gallery plugin loads, but images are not visible?
Link to site:

```
  http://81.21.192.171/~lasy/galeria/
```

And if you see code on a site, below sign "Galeria" there are some photos... but not visible. I do not know why...

Comment: There are no img tags, just divs with data attributes (to be loaded via js), and in the js console you have an error "TweenMax is undefined" - seems the plugin is not loading the correct javascript. Report it to the plugin developers

Comment: IMG tag is inside div class "imageUIContainer". But as a metter of fact, TweenMax is not defined, so maybe it is a problem.

Comment: Ok, yes i see them. They have their opacity set to 0 in a style tag, preumably to be changed by js. The problem remains a js one.

Comment: Thats why I wrote to developer.. we will see.... Thanks for help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Because the link does not work anymore, i found the clue in the title and the comments to the question:

- comment about undefined TweenMax
- title refers to "metro gallery" which seems to be [Metro Wordpress Grid Portfolio](http://codecanyon.net/item/metro-wordpress-grid-portfolio/6618922) plugin which includes TweenMax

Try to check for any active plugin that includes TweenLite, for example the "LayerSlider WP" which is recommended by the Avada theme, and contains TweenLite in their JS collection.

To understand the issue, you should read this [Greensock forum thread](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/8602-uncaught-referenceerror-tweenmax-is-not-defined/)